# Plotly Category Line Plot

Tags: plotly, line-plot, plotly.js

Is it possible to create a category line plot in plotly.js, where the x-axis has two levels of categories?

For an example of what I mean by this, see the line plot on [this link](https://peltiertech.com/chart-with-a-dual-category-axis/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use subplots that share the Y axis but each have its own categorical X axis. Something like this:

```
var trace1 = {
  name: 'type1',
  x: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  y: [10, 11, 12],
  type: 'scatter',
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace2 = {
  name: 'type2',
  x: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  y: [10, 11, 12],
  xaxis: 'x2',
  type: 'scatter',
  mode: 'lines'
};

var trace3 = {
  name: 'type2',
  x: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
  y: [10, 11, 12],
  xaxis: 'x3',
  type: 'scatter',
  mode: 'lines'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {domain: [0, 0.33]},
  xaxis2: {domain: [0.33, 0.66]},
  xaxis3: {domain: [0.66, 1]}
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```